# Zeros of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

If an analytic function has a single zero, can it only be a linear function? This is obviously correct for finite order polynomials yet is it true for all analytic functions?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true: The function $z e^z$ has only a single zero, of order $1$ at the origin. More generally, any analytic function without zeros can be used to construct a counterexample of this sort.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I know that this question of mine may be naive yet are not points at "infinity" with Real{z} = - Infinity also zeros of (ze^{z})?

Comment: There are no points at infinity that belong to $\mathbb C$ (Gauß plane). If at all, there is one point of infinity in the Riemann sphere. And there, $\exp$ has an essential singulariy

Comment: Thank you very much- I am very grateful to your responses. (Perhaps I should have not used the words "point at infinity"- I just meant to note that along the line Real z = -Infinity, the analytic function ze^{z} vanishes.)

Comment: Thank you very much again! A related aspect is that the function ze^{z} might not be analytic on the Riemann sphere as you note. However, are there any functions that are analytic everywhere on the Riemann sphere with a single zero that are not linear functions? I sincerely apologize for my naive questions and am very thankful for your help.

Comment: @user153388 The only meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere are rational functions, and the only entire functions are constants.